# What will happen if AWS ElastiCache Redis Memory is full?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

What will happen if AWS ElastiCache Redis Memory is full and we again try to insert more data in it? I am trying to find this answer but haven't got a sufficient answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setting called maxmemory-policy which controls this. You have to edit the Parameter Group for your ElastiCache cluster. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/ParameterGroups.Redis.html